# How to get current Item in Custom Form Action Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

On custom edit page of list item, I want to do the following 
- On clicking Form Action Hyperlink [DataView Control], custom form action will fire to update 
a item hidden field [Status].

I already tried the following 
- Passing @ID to the work flow but didnt work
- Create a duplicate ID column and updated it with the ID on Item Creation. and then tried to access in "Update Item in" Action but getting "An unexpected error has occurred" while running it.

[Remember i can only use sharepoint designer]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these javascript functions:

```
function GetQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
            return pair[1];
        }
    }
}

function GetCurrentItem() {
    var itemId = GetQueryVariable("ID");
    try {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('list-title');
        this.currItem = list.getItemById(itemId);

        context.load(currItem);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.funcSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.funcFailed));
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}

function funcSuccess() {}
function funcFailed() {}
```